# Least number of whole tiles to use to fill a space

Tags: excel, excel-formula, combinations, mathematical-optimization, vba

Per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31542620/constant-rectangles-to-fill-variable-rectangular-space), Tim makes a good point so trying this again. He writes,

> The problem of minimizing the total number of smaller rectangles used
>   to fill the total space is a very real world problem. Just take a look
>   at the floor of your bathroom and you'll see why. A mason needs to
>   know how he can cover a space destroying the least number of tiles,
>   and depending on the algorithm used he will get different results.

So, if you have a space of W width and L length and a constant rectangle of 48 width and 96 length, what's the best way to fill said space with minimum waste?

There's [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19760755/number-of-ways-to-fill-a-nxm-grid) which gives all combinations so I could run through it all and pick best solution. I don't understand the answer/java though XD

Comment: Since you like formulas rolled up into one cell, I thought you might find [the formula in column L](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475961/how-to-autogenerate-certain-excel-strings-from-certain-inputs-as-given-in-exampl/37489151#37489151) up your alley

Answer (score 0):

Unless the big surface is an even multiple of the tile dimensions, you will have to cut **some** tiles and there will be **some** waste.  Say we have a perfect saw that can cut a tile with zero waste.  We cut each 96 x 48  tile into 4608 1 x 1 squares.  To determine the number of tiles we need, we divide the total area of the big surface by 4608 and round up to the nearest integer tile!

Comment: Not bad. Actually brilliant. But only in theory? A mason wouldn't chop up his tiles into 1x1 squares XD It makes perfect (mathematical) sense but with a CONSTANT rectangle, wouldn't orientation matter? Depending on the space, lying it horizontally vs vertically, it has to make a difference? I would include example but I think we can both picture it without. Still +1 for theory/logic.

Comment: @findwindow What is critical is that both the length & width of the big surface must be **integer** units...that is, not something like *1345&1/4*  That way the big surface can be entirely filed by *1x1*'s

Comment: Excellent point. I made that presumption but in practice, spaces are rarely integers XD That's an additional curveball! Edit: Actually, it's only critical because space isn't a square?

Comment: @findwindow What if you are placing your rectangle in a herringbone pattern?

Comment: @ForwardEd so you're the one trolling me =P Actually, I am placing it in a star shape.