# How to autogenerate certain excel strings from certain inputs as given in example?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007, vba

Basically I want the following in excel:

I need that, if I Input following in Sheet 1:

```html
      A       B       C
1   Name    Size    Color
2   Shirt   S,M,L   Red, Green
3   Trouser 32,34   White, Black, Grey
```

The following output automatically generates in Sheet 2:

```html
     A                  B     C
1   Name               Size Color
2   Shirt-S-Red         S   Red
3   Shirt-M-Red         M   Red
4   Shirt-L-Red         L   Red
5   Shirt-S-Green       S   Green
6   Shirt-M-Green       M   Green
7   Shirt-L-Green       L   Green
8   Trouser-32-White    32  White
9   Trouser-34-White    34  White
10  Trouser-32-Black    32  Black
11  Trouser-34-Black    34  Black
12  Trouser-32-Grey     32  Grey
13  Trouser-34-Grey     34  Grey
```

Basically, the all the child rows should be generated from the parent rows, like rows 2 to 7 of Sheet 2 have been generated from Row 2 of Sheet 1, and so on.

Further elaborating, Need such a kind of formula that if I add an another row in Sheet 1 with three Sizes and three Colors of Waistcoat, then the formula or the script should automatically insert further 9 rows to Sheet 2 after Row 13 (i.e., with 9 Permutations and Combinations of Input in Row 4 of Sheet 1).

How can I achieve this using Excel formulas or VB Script? Please tell me the solution.

Thanks.

P.S.: I have tried my best to describe this problem of mine. Please comment, if something is ambiguous in understanding the problem, I shall then further elaborate on that point.

Comment: You are posting on the wrong StackExchange site. [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) is a *site for professional and enthusiast programmers*; a place for getting specific answers to targeted, focused questions. It is not a place to post a description of your problems (with or without the *[I looked everywhere](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/283163)* disclaimer). If you want to dump your problems on someone else without demonstrating any original effort toward solving your problem you should be posting in [StackOverflow Jobs](http://stackoverflow.com/jobs).

Answer (score 1):

This can be down but I needed to use a small helper table to keep the counts of the number of size items in each row, the number of colours in each row, and finally a running total of the possible combinations for each row.

Proof of Concept

[image: Proof of Concept]

Caveats

Yes, there is more than one!

- Sizes must remain consistant in number of characters.  7,8,9 or 10,11,12 is ok but 8,9,10 will not work.  Work around is to use leading 0s.
- Colours needs to be one continuous separated by a space. Comas will be removed.  Red, Bright-Red Infra_Red are ok, but Blood Red is not.
- You will need to adjust your ranges to suit your data.

Based on the data in the proof of concept image above, use these formulas in row 3 and copy down.

Column F:

```
=(LEN(B2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B2,",",""))+1)
```

Column G:

```
=(LEN(C2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(C2,",",""))+1)
```

The above two formulas count the number of comas.  Based on that number they determine the number of items in show for the row, and the number of different colours for the row.

Column H:

```
=F3*G3+H2
```

This keeps a running total of the number of combinations for each row.

Column J:

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$4,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),$H$3:$H$5,1)+1,1))&"-"&K3&"-"&L3
```

This pulls the name from the list in A2:A4 advancing the row as the formula is dragged down based on the running total of combinations.  It then concatenates the string with "-" and text from adjacent columns.

Column K:

```
=MID(INDEX($B$2:$B$4,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),$H$3:$H$5,1)+1,1)),MOD((ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2)-IFERROR(INDEX($H$3:$H$5,MATCH(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),$H$3:$H$5,1)),0)),INDEX($F$3:$F$5,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),$H$3:$H$5,1)+1,1)))*FIND(",",INDEX($B$2:$B$4,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),$H$3:$H$5,1)+1,1)))+1,FIND(",",INDEX($B$2:$B$4,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),$H$3:$H$5,1)+1,1)))-1)
```

Where to begin with that bad boy above...Lets just say I broke it out into sever columns first and then back substitute those formulas as required until I got this.  It basically pulls out the size letters in sequence and then starts again at the next colour.  May have been simpler to make it dependent on the colour name change in the adjacent column.  This formula is independent. of the colour name column.

Column L:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(INDEX($C$2:$C$4,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),$H$3:$H$5,1)+1,1))," ",REPT(" ",LEN(INDEX($C$2:$C$4,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),$H$3:$H$5,1)+1,1))))),((QUOTIENT(ROWS($A$2:A2)-1-IFERROR(INDEX($H$3:$H$5,MATCH(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),$H$3:$H$5,1)),0),(INDEX($H$3:$H$5,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),$H$3:$H$5,1)+1,1))-IFERROR(INDEX($H$3:$H$5,MATCH(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),$H$3:$H$5,1)),0))/INDEX($G$3:$G$5,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),$H$3:$H$5,1)+1,1))))*LEN(INDEX($C$2:$C$4,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),$H$3:$H$5,1)+1,1))))+1,LEN(INDEX($C$2:$C$4,IFERROR(MATCH(ROW(A2)-ROW($A$2),$H$3:$H$5,1)+1,1))))),",","")
```

Similar to the previous formula this was developed over several columns and then brought back into one cell.  It blows apart the colour names, and then grabs each name in sequence after the number of rows equal to the number of sizes has past.

Comment: Do you get paid by the word or something =P

Comment: You have too much time on your hands. Also, are you combing through all my old questions?

Comment: @findwindow no, just figured it was a good way to point something out to you without bogging down someone else's question.

Comment: Oh, you could have pinged me here XD I ask because someone is up/downvoting some of my very old questions. Edit: I felt stalked I guess XD Edit2: last time I am upvoting anything of yours over 10 words.

Comment: @findwindow _Normally_ I try to explain so people can learn from it and maybe make their own adjustments.  That or work with someone to get them to their solution if they are demonstrating some effort on their part to work and learn.  I find that hard to do with 10 words or less.  Thankfully I am not just dragging you to my post for you upvotes!  But I do appreciate them.  I was a bit perplexed by the end result of my own formula this time so I was actually trying to avoid explaining them in detail.

Comment: lol fine, 11 words =P I prefer no explanation in answers so I can figure it out myself.

Comment: @findwindow Should I make my answers spoilers after showing the main formula as the lead off?

Comment: lolololololol I am pulling your chain =P But yea, that's kinda funny! Edit2: well, in this case, I won't be able to figure out column L though =PP

Comment: @findwindow, I can't figure out L!  you should see all the columns off to the side that I built it from.  Most of those I can explain!  But I did not want to bog down imgur with so many screen shots! 8)

Comment: Machines are amazing eh. Thoughtless yet can execute code humans can't explain. (Regarding the upvote, I know what it's like to spend time on an answer for the OP not to care^^;)

Comment: Sir, I bow to you. You are great. Such a great tutorial. Wow. Many thanks for your favor. I personally had spent nearly 10 days in Excel for solving this query. But, you are great. Thanks...and I mean it from heart.