# Excel - Finding first character that is not 0 in a string

Tags: excel

My cell A1 will have a string in it such as 02020. I need a formula that will check this string and return the value of the first character that is not equal to 0. So in the above example it should return 2.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Show your formula.

Comment: I don't have a formula, the formula is what I'm asking for.

Comment: SO isn't an Excel service.

Comment: What do you mean by that? Excel has formulas such as Find, search, match etc. I'm asking if there is one that I can use to invert the logic so it returns a position or character if it does not match.

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Was the post really that cryptic?

Comment: Sigh XD `To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: Search, and research` Edit: hint - you mentioned `find`. Try that.

Comment: Find is for finding a substring within a string. This is not what im after. Same goes for search. I want it to be NOT EQUAL to the substring.

Comment: I don't have the patience for this XD Good day.

Comment: You misplaced the word "intelligence" with "patience"

Comment: Wow look at that. Imagine if you applied that effort into solving your problem. Edit: also good try to get me to answer but troll harder. You're looking at SO's best troll, if I say so myself^^

Comment: @findwindow - troll cannot get the **left**-most character from the **value** of a cell. Move on... nothing to see here.

Comment: @Jeeped missed you~ Next time I require you to submit a request of absence =P

Comment: `=MID(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"0","")),1,1)` OR `=LEFT(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"0","")),1)`

Comment: `=LEFT(VALUE(A1))` (¹didn't realize this was *'complex formula development'*).

Comment: @ScottCraner always the saint ;_; whyyyyyyyy ;___;

Comment: @Jeeped did not realize till just now that the number of characters in the Left() function is optional.  Learning things today, time to go home.

Comment: @Jeeped lol that's..... brilliant^^ Edit: wait, `complex formula development'` lololololololol

Comment: Only on the worksheet @ScottCraner, not in VBA. fwiw, same for similar functions like CODE.

Comment: @findwindow I genuinely wasn't trying to trick you into answering. You came across as not understanding my question. If you read through it again I'm sure you'll see why I thought that. As for me snapping at you in my reply well that's because you were being patronising. As for SO not being an excel service, thats a fair point. I didn't realise that as most excel questions I research tend to lead me here.

Comment: Just for the record OP, all you had to do was show one formula you tried that didn't work and all of this could have been avoided.

Comment: @ScottCraner thank you! Much appreciated

Comment: WAIT  Did I hear someone ask for a complex formula??? 8)  Muahahaha  EDIT: @Findwindow...since muahahaha is not a word, that was 10 words or less 8)

Comment: @ForwardEd - Sadly no. Just someone who didn't read the [excel] tag description before posting.

Comment: @ForwardEd please accept this coupon to redeem for a free upvote. Valid until 12/31/2016

Comment: @Jeeped inside joke between me and Ed XD

Comment: @findwindow - no worries; I never seem to get jokes anyways. Geez, I have to lookup things like 8) and XD.

Comment: @Jeeped lol but you _do_ at least my terrible ones ^_^; If truly interested see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37475961/how-to-autogenerate-certain-excel-strings-from-certain-inputs-as-given-in-exampl/37489151?noredirect=1#comment62478724_37489151) Gonna start my weekend~ Edit: lol awww, I make sure not to do =^.^= then =PP

Comment: :P~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ or is it :P''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''' but the only high-five I know is ⁵

Comment: @Jeeped you do get jokes...I remember distinctly "BRAINS -> NOT FOUND"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only important issue is that a leading zero may be the first character in a string of characters, or it may simply be the result of formatting a numeric value with leading zeros.  The solution should cover both cases.

Consider this User Defined Function:

```
Public Function DropTheZeros(r As Range) As Variant
    Dim s As String, i As Long

    s = r(1).Text
    For i = 1 To Len(s)
        DropTheZeros = Mid(s, i, 1)
        If DropTheZeros <> "0" Then Exit Function
    Next i
    DropTheZeros = ""
End Function
```

[image]

*This should work even if the leading zeros are an artifice of formatting.*

Or even:

```
Public Function DropTheZeros2(r As Range) As Variant
    DropTheZeros2 = Left(Replace(r(1).Text, "0", ""), 1)
End Function
```

Or even without VBA:

```
=LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(TEXT(A1,"@"),"0",""),1)
```

Comment: (as per the comments) You don't need the `, 1`